# Clarifying rownum order of operations in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, rownum

According to this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html), when using `rownum` in a query, it is called in the following order of operations.

```
The FROM/WHERE clause goes first.
ROWNUM is assigned and incremented to each output row from the FROM/WHERE clause.
SELECT is applied.
GROUP BY is applied.
HAVING is applied.
ORDER BY is applied.
```

I want to know where the `AND` would be categorized on this list.  Would it be evaluated at the same time as the `WHERE`?  What if the `WHERE` has a `rownum` and the `AND` does not?

Comment: Which `AND` are you referring to?  `AND` is not a clause - it's a keyword that combines expressions to make up part of a clause.  As such, it will be evaluated as whatever clause it is part of...

Comment: AND just adds additional constraints on the WHERE clause.

Comment: @OldProgrammer . . . `AND` could also be used in a `case` statement that could appear in the `select`, `group by`, `having`, and `order by` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AND has no role in this. When result set is being constructed, the rownum is assigned to the results before outermost ordering. Filtering on ROWNUM is a hard stop from feeding results up from deeper in the execution plan. Therefore for example a construct like `where rownum > 5` returns no rows.

Hopefully this helps. If not, please elaborate in your question and/or explain why you are asking. There are alternatives that are sometimes better, such as `row_number()`.

Answer (score -1):

I just had an update not work that had where field_value is not null and rownum = 1.
since rownum = 1 was for a row that had field_value = null that was the row it tired to return and then no action occurred in the update.

So with in the Where clause there is also an order of operation.
need to put () around it or make it a sub query to be sure rownum is on the results of the other parts of the where cause.

I used a distinct instead of rownum = 1 for my case.

Comment: Please expand on this explanation, it is not very clear and only addresses one specific case rather than the general question.